# webmaster tools api: How to get top keywords for specific dates

Tags: python, google-search-console

I am truing to make a request to webmaster tools to get top keywords for specific dates. E.g. 2012-10-01 - 2012-09-01 on my website. Is there a way to make such requests? (I am using this lib http://code.google.com/p/webmaster-tools-downloads/ to gather data)